# C# wia + network scanner How do I connect?

Tags: c#, wia, wsd

I can enumerate local devices, I can find the DeviceId of the scanner I want to connect to in the registry. CommonDialog only enumerates local devices. DeviceId is read-only.

How do I either enumerate devices on the network and then connect or connect with a known DevicedId?

Thanks

Comment: Could you tell us more about your question? Are you developing the app from scratch based on the wia specification or using a third-party SDK?

Comment: We went another direction, thanks for trying to help. New to the list and was expecting an email when a post was made. Thanks again.